# Netplan static IP subnets - am I accidentally adding extra IPs?

Tags: networking, server, netplan, static-ip

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this so sorry if not.
I've configured a machine running ubuntu server on my network to have two local static IPs like so:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.155/24
      - 192.168.1.156/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.0.0.1
  version: 2
```

With this I can ping my machine with both 192.168.1.155 and 192.168.1.156.

Now I'm new to networking but I know that the a /24 mask means all the addresses in the 192.168.1 range, but what does it mean in the case of netplan when I'm supposed to be giving specific IP addresses? Am I allocating more IPs by accident? What would happen if I changed it to /32? Thanks.

Comment: with the /24 you are defining your sub-net mask of 24 bits. No, you are not allocating more IP's by accident. Do not change it to /32.

Comment: So is the 24 bit mask where it can access any other devices in 192.168.1.0 without the gateway? I'm assuming changing to /32 would take away my LAN access?

Comment: That's correct. The netmask declares the range of other ips on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of netplan's `address` configuration entry, `/24` indicates the netmask of the network the specified address belongs to, and hence the range of addresses which are directly reachable through that interface.

```
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.155/24
```

means: "Assign the interface the IPv4 address 192.168.1.155 and the netmask /24." So if you later do a `ping 192.168.1.234` the OS will know that the destination address is on the same network and try to locate it via ARP (in the case of Ethernet).

```
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.155/24
  - 192.168.1.156/24
```

will assign two addresses within the same subnet, setting the netmask to `/24` both times, somewhat redundantly.

If you changed it to `/32` then the netmask of the interface would be set to `/32` instead, meaning that no other addresses except those of the interface itself are directly reachable through it. So `ping 192.168.1.234` would look for a suitable next hop in the routing table, probably hitting the default gateway. If the default gateway is itself in the `192.168.1.0/24` network then it will not be reachable either, so a routing error will occur.